# Is the closure of an open holomorphically convex subset of a Stein space holomorphically convex?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, analytic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let X be a Stein manifold and U an open, connected, relatively compact, holomorphically convex subset of X. Is the closure of U in X holomorphically convex?

Also, if X is a Stein *space* with a finite number of singularities, and U is an open, connected, relatively compact, holomorphically convex subset of X containing all the singularities, is it true that the closure of U is holomorphically convex in this case too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

In fact, in the first page of the paper

P.J. de Paepe, "Closures of proper analytic polyedra", Compositio mathematica 28 (1974), p. 333-341

there is the example of a relatively compact Stein space $U \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ such that its closure $\bar{U}$ is **not** holomorphically convex.

The example is as follows:

$U:=\{(z, w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \, | \, |z| < |w|, \frac{1}{2} < |w| <1 \} \cup \{(z, w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \, | \, |w| < |z|, \frac{1}{2} < |z| <1 \} $.

In fact, the smallest holomorphic set containing $\bar{U}$ is the unit polidisk in $\mathbb{C}^2$, which is different from $\bar{U}$.

**EDIT**. In a previous version of this post I wrote that the answer to the question was positive, since I erroneously assumed that the closure of $U$ was a complex space, see BCnrd's comment below.

Comment: Why is $Y$ a complex space?

Comment: You are completely right, I wrote this answer in auto-pilot. In fact, there are compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ which are not holomorphically convex (see for instance [Freeman-Harvey, Pacific J. of Mathematics 48]. I've edited the post 